# Xcode 8.1 beta connection Unavailable

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode8

I just installed Xcode 8.1 beta. Now I am trying to run my app on iPhone 6 with iOS 10.1 beta. But I am getting this weird error.

Connection Unavailable

The prefetchDataSource outlet was added in iOS10.0; create the connection in code to avoid crashes on earlier versions.

Main.StoryBoard

[image]

Comment: Did you try a clean? Also this sounds like a coredata issue. What are you trying to link up for the outlet?

Comment: Yeah I cleaned it. If I change deployment target to 10.1 it works otherwise it still giving me same error. I am not using core data in my app. I am using fire base.

Comment: Are you in fact using the `prefetchDataSource` outlet? If so, do what the error message says. Delete it and set the `prefetchDataSource` in code instead.

Comment: I encountered this issue on a `UICollectionView`. I added a couple of lines of code to an unrelated portion of my project with a recently updated version of Xcode. prefetchDataSource was on the UICollectionView with the prior working  build, but updating Xcode triggered the error. I was able to resolve it with the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved same problem.

In your project, delete the `prefetchDataSource`. :)

look this picture

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem... just avoids it until you actually need to use the feature.

Comment: Does not fix the problem if you want to use prefetchDataSource !!

Answer (score 1):

Removing this did the trick for me.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I searched for "collection view" in the storyboard and removed the prefetchdatasource connection.